# Change display order of checkout buttons in Magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I need to place checkout buttons in shopping cart page in order

```
1) Proceed to checkout 
2) Google checkout 
3) Paypal Express
```

checkout.xml
inside

```
      <checkout_cart_index>
          <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" translate="label">
                <label>Payment Methods After Checkout Button</label>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage"  as="testproceed" after="-" template="checkout/onepage/link.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/multishipping_link" name="checkout.cart.methods.multishipping" template="checkout/multishipping/link.phtml"/>
            </block>
```

googlecheckout.xml

```
     <reference name="checkout.cart.methods">
        <block type="googlecheckout/link" name="checkout.cart.methods.googlecheckout.bottom" after="testproceed" as="testgoogle" template="googlecheckout/link.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

paypal.xml

```
    <reference name="checkout.cart.methods">
        <block type="paypal/express_shortcut" name="checkout.cart.methods.paypal_express.bottom" as="testpaypal"  after="testgoogle"  template="paypal/express/shortcut.phtml">
            <action method="setIsQuoteAllowed"><value>1</value></action>
             <action method="setIsInCatalogProduct"><value>1</value></action>
                <action method="setShowOrPosition"><value>before</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

But not getting in correct order.
Please help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just change

```
      <block type="paypal/express_shortcut" after="checkout.cart.methods.googlecheckout.bottom"  name="checkout.cart.methods.paypal_express.bottom"  template="paypal/express/shortcut.phtml">
```